# parsing c++ / tracing void pointers

Tags: c++, parsing

In my codebase, I ve got a lot function declarations with void-pointers as argument

```
void my_func(void* my_void_pointer)
```

I need to find all places in my sources

1. where my_func is called
2. (more importantly) with which type as argument.

For example calls like:

```
int* intpt=new int(10);
my_func(intpt);
```

or

```
char* charpt = new char('a');
my_func(charpt);
```

I need this because usually my_func does a `reinterpret_cast` to some self defined types and I would like to find out what possibly could go wrong if for example my byteorder changes.

I have already had a look at gcc_xml, but with this tool I can only find out which functions are defined with which arguments/argument types. Of course I could now grep the sources for function calls of such functions, but I still do not know with which types they are called with. Any idea which tool to start with?

Comment: I hope you see why this was a bad idea (i.e. to use `void*` as a type-erased argument), unless this is for a C interface, in which case the interface could contain a typename suffix and do the correct conversion at that layer, preventing your own code at least from hacking typesafety.

Comment: Unfortunately I see very clearly why it is a bad Idea to hack typesafety. In this case I need to handle legacy code which is to be migrated to another platform and I need to find out at which points it would break

Comment: I feel for you then `:)`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the argument to a non-pointer and recompile. You should get errors like `cannot convert int* to int` or `cannot convert char* to int` wherever your function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Start with your compiler. Go and break the prototype and implementation of `my_func` by renaming it to `Xmy_func` (or any other change) and recompile... the compiler will tell you every place it's used.

Comment: Thanks, great idea, but how do I then find out with which argument types it is called?

Comment: If you have an IDE that lets you click on an error to jump to the line of code containing it, you do that for each case and use Eyeball(2.0) to inspect what arguments are being used :)

Comment: Thanks, the modification by @mark-tolonen solves it: I will change the argument list and grep for the occurences

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small utility using [Clang Tooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. Use the following command to serach the occureneces of my_func in source directory.

```
grep "my_func(" *
```

Option 2. Use of source navigator. Open the source in source navigator and search the function name "my_func".

Answer (score 0):

If you working in *nix terminal, you can try something like this:

```
// in project root folder
// you can replace *.cpp with *.h or *.hpp etc
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.cpp"); do \
grep -Hn "my_func" $i; \
done;
```

Comment: -Hn option output to you file name and line number, where function exists.

Comment: There's also the ultra-fast [Silver search](http://geoff.greer.fm/2011/12/27/the-silver-searcher-better-than-ack/) as an alternative to grep.

Comment: yes, but this does not help me to find with which argument types the function is called, so whether i call `my_func` with an int* variable or with a `char*`

Comment: In this case, mah's answer is your go. You could also change the prototype of the function to take something that can't be casted as `void*` natively. This ans a bit of log analysis will give you a view of which types are used/

Answer (score 0):

With a modern IDE, such as [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), you can search for all occurrences of each of your functions and explore call sites. Note however that Eclipse CDT doesn't appear to be able to distinguish overloads when searching, as its Java counterpart does.